# laravel jetstream modify RegisteredUserController

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

i'm trying to display some data from my database and display it on my register blade(jetstream auth), i tried to modify the create function on RegisteredUserController but it didn't work
i tried to modify the controller as this

```
public function create(Request $request): RegisterViewResponse
    {
        $x=5;
        return app(RegisterViewResponse::class,['x'=>$x]);
    }
```

and i got the following error :

> Undefined variable $x (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\za3ma\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you’ve tried and what’s not working?

Comment: @Peppermintology https://imgur.com/3KqG3GX and for the error i got Undefined variable  Undefined variable $x (View: \resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

Comment: Post your code with your question as **code formatted text**, not as screenshot

Comment: did you try `return view('auth.register', ['x' => $x]);`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! To be able to modify your jetstream Login view

- First, open the **JetstreamServiceProverder** class in your **providers** folder
- Then add the following code to the **boot** method in the service provider

  ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
   use Inertia\Inertia;
   use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

   Fortify::loginView(function () {
       $x = 5;

       return view('auth.login', [
           'x' => $x,
       ]);
   });
  ```

You can add more logics to it.